# Converting Pixels to a BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, pixel

I have a 2D integer array that represents pixel grayscale intensity values:

```
0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 
0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 
0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 
0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 
0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 
0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 
0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 
0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 
0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 
0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255 0 255
```

Clearly, there are 5 vertical lines which will be black once converted to an image.
However, my final image has 5 horizontal lines instead. I do not understand why I am getting the black horizontal lines, not the vertical lines. Changing pixel[i][j] to pixel[j][i] makes vertical lines, but that's not what I am looking for. I'd like to know why my picture has 5 horizontal black lines while my pixel values have 5 vertical black lines.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        SampleModel sm = null;
        WritableRaster writeRaster = null;
        Raster raster = null;
        int[][] pixel = new int[10][10];

        // containing only white pixels in an image
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
                pixel[i][j] = 255;
        printPixels(pixel);

        // make black vertical lines by changing intensity value
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j+=2) 
                pixel[i][j] = 0;
        printPixels(pixel);

        image = new BufferedImage(10, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        raster = image.getData();
        sm = raster.getSampleModel();
        writeRaster = Raster.createWritableRaster(sm, new Point(0, 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                 writeRaster.setSample(i, j, 0, pixel[i][j]);
            }
        }
        image.setData(writeRaster);
        writeFile(image, "modified.gif");
    }
}
```

Comment: Different coordinate system.

Comment: `setSample` is in `x`/`y` coordinate systems

Comment: *"Changing pixel[i][j] to pixel[j][i] makes vertical lines, but that's not what I am looking for."* Why not?

Answer (score 0):

The coordinate system of the `Raster` (i.e. `writeRaster`) is different than that of `SampleModel`. According to the documentation for `Raster`:

> Although a Raster may live anywhere in the plane, a `SampleModel` makes
>   use of a simple coordinate system that starts at `(0, 0)`. A Raster
>   therefore contains a translation factor that allows pixel locations to
>   be mapped between the `Raster`'s coordinate system and that of the
>   `SampleModel`. The translation from the `SampleModel` coordinate system to
>   that of the Raster may be obtained by the `getSampleModelTranslateX` and
>   `getSampleModelTranslateY` methods.

Additionally, the documentation states:

> A `Raster` encapsulates a `DataBuffer` that stores the sample values and a
>   `SampleModel` that describes how to locate a given sample value in a
>   `DataBuffer`.

Taking those two statements together, samples in `Raster` are the transpose of those in a standard coordinate plane, hence the inclusion of the `getSampleModelTranslateX` and `getSampleModelTranslateY` methods in the `Raster` class. Thus, supplying coordinates to the `setSample` method uses that transposed coordinate system. The correct way to account for this is to reverse the *x* and *y* coordinates in your code. This may seem like a hack, but this is a proper procedure since the two coordinate systems are transposed. Your code would then be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    SampleModel sm = null;
    WritableRaster writeRaster = null;
    Raster raster = null;
    int[][] pixel = new int[10][10];

    // containing only white pixels in an image
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
            pixel[i][j] = 255;
    printPixels(pixel);

    // make black vertical lines by changing intensity value
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j+=2) 
            pixel[i][j] = 0;
    printPixels(pixel);

    image = new BufferedImage(10, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    raster = image.getData();
    sm = raster.getSampleModel();
    writeRaster = Raster.createWritableRaster(sm, new Point(0, 0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
             writeRaster.setSample(i, j, 0, pixel[j][i]); // <--- Note: Reversal of i and j
        }
    }
    image.setData(writeRaster);
    writeFile(image, "modified.gif");
}
```